# Clicking gears on new Electra Townie 8i

Tags: chain, repair, lubricant, internally-geared-hub

I asked a similar question related to slipping gears here:

- [Slipping gears on new Electra Townie 8i](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/5855/slipping-gears-on-new-electra-townie-8i)

but now I no longer get slipping, but clicking noise when the pedals are rotated either forward or backward direction, but not when coasting and the pedals are not moving.  When in low gear, the clicking is faster and slower in high gear.

Could this clicking be the chain clicking on the sprockets of the gears?  What is the source of this noise and how can I fix it?  My other Townie 8i does not have this noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be many issues, but a click in the hub which is a rotary noise, is usually the Chain guard or the dust cap on the hub behind the cog which has popped out of place, or possibly cracked.

The noise is not detrimental to the safety of the bike, but you should find a shop that has experience repairing these hubs, and get them to do a rebuild.